# With body background set to black, a button and its text completely gray out when disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css

With body background set to black, a button and its text completely gray out when disabled, making it unreadable.  This is on a Mac, and otherwise works on a PC.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:black">
<input type='button' value='Test' disabled='true'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I'm getting:
[image: Here's what I'm getting]

If anyone can fix, please let me know!

In response to the answer below by Prikesh, here is an additional screenshot after applying the style:
[image]

Other than enabled/disabled, the button border and size are now different.

Comment: what do you see in your safari? can you share a image?

Comment: Also you may have to use `webkit` for safari browser to make it as you desire.

Comment: What browser? I can read it just fine on Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried just setting a style for the button as an override?

Comment: Just added a screenshot.  This is on Safari, but similar on Firefox.

Comment: Rather than adding links to your questions, please embed the code and pictures directly into the question using the toolbar while you are composing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is macOS fault...

Browsers use the [System Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atMeF.png) `ButtonFace` for buttons' `background-color`, so the OS dictates what color is being used. On macOS it's white (`0xFFFFFFFF`) normally and a **semi-transparent** white when the input is disabled (`0xFFFFFF80`).
Similarly, they set the `color` to the system color `ButtonText` which defaults to black (`0x00000000`) normally and to a semi-opaque black when disabled (`0x00000033`).
The `ButtonFace` color also has an other variation to a blueish gradient color when :active.

This means that when your <button> is disabled, the OS will actually lower its opacity, which is indeed a problem when your background is black.

Here is a fiddle for macOS users:

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<button disabled>disabled</button>
<button>enabled</button>
```

And a screenshot for others.

[image: screenshot of the Snippet's result ran on macOS]

As you can see, the disabled button is actually transparent.

To overcome this, you have no options but to define your own styles, because they use semi-transparent colors rather than an `opactiy` you could have easily overwritten. Though beware even the borders are affected by these System Colors and since other OS may have there own different behaviors w.r.t all these states, you may have to define the styles for all the different states, not just for disabled.

PS: Fun fact for Chrome browser. If you do change your browser's zoom level, then it will stop using the System Color and the color won't be transparent anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can just override the styles of the button if it is in a disabled state.

```css
input[type="button"]:disabled {
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="background-color:black">
  <input type='button' value='Test' />
  <input type='button' value='Test' disabled='true' />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works, but the button looks different now when compared to enabled button.  Can't add screenshot here, but I'll add another screenshot in the original post.

Comment: So, the change in background caused it. removed the background change. you can make it any other colour that you prefer and it should look similar in size and design from your normal button. And if you are gonna use a css frame work. you can let that handle the button styles anyways

Comment: Yes, the background does seem to be causing it.  If I don't change the background and just change the color, the button shape doesn't change and I can read the text.  Thank you.