# Animation fill mode "forwards" overwriting :active style

Tags: html, css

I'm currently developing a css theme for YouTube.com and I'm faced with a particular issue:

An animation I've applied for buttons is set to have the fill mode "forwards" so that it stays at its final frame. However, doing this overwrites any style I apply with the :active rule.

How do I get around this?

```css
@keyframes button_hoverin {
 from { background: white; }
 to { background: red; }
}

@keyframes button_hoverout {
 from { background: red; }
 to { background: white; }
}

#button {
 animation: button_hoverout 0.5s forwards;
}

#button:hover {
    animation: button_hoverin 0.5s forwards;
}

#button:active {
  background: blue !important; /* even with "!important" it's overwritten.*/
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Button sample</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply reset the `animation-fill-mode` in `:active`:

```css
@keyframes button_hoverin {
  from { background: white; }
  to { background: red; }
}

@keyframes button_hoverout {
  from { background: red; }
  to { background: white; }
}

#button {
  animation: button_hoverout 0.5s forwards;
}

#button:hover {
  animation: button_hoverin 0.5s forwards;
}

#button:active {
  background: blue;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Button sample</button>
```

However note that Chrome on macOs doesn't run at all your animation (probably because they have trouble with System Colors. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60881041/3702797) for more info).